# D3 - Retrieve data associated with a clicked element in the chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I have a stacked bar chart which is build correctly using **D3**.
The original data looks like this:

```
var originalData = {
            
header: ["label", "count", "missing"],
rows:   [
            {label: "A", count: 0, missing: 0},
            {label: "B", count: 24, missing: 59},
            {label: "C", count: 6, missing: 77},
            {label: "D", count: 7, missing: 76},
            {label: "E", count: 2, missing: 81},
            {label: "F", count: 7, missing: 76},    
            {label: "G", count: 0, missing: 83}
        ]
};
```

So each bar is a stack of bars which represent the amount of **count** and **missing** quantities.
This `originalData` is passed to the `d3.stack` function to generate the stacked bar object to be used to draw the rectangles.

```
var barChartObject = d3.stack().keys(originalData.header.slice(1) )
                                  .value( (d,key) => d[key] )
                                  (originalData.rows);
```

The resulting object is something like this:

```
[
    [[0,0],[0,24],[0,6],[0,7],[0,2],[0,7],[0,0]]
    [[0,0],[24,83],[6,83],[7,83],[2,83],[7,83],[0,83]]
]
```

NOTE: Every "pair" is actually an object which contains the original data used to built the pair and such data is available in the `.data` field.

The code which draw the rectangles look like this:

```
onBarClick = (event, data) => {

    ...    
}

var barGroupTag = this.svg.selectAll()
                       .data(barChartObject)
                       .enter()
                       .append("g")

barGroupTag.selectAll("rect")
        .data(d => d)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        ...
        .on("mouseover", this.onMouseOverBar)
        .on("mouseout", this.onMouseOutBar)
        .on('click', this.onBarClick);
```

Then the rects are manually wrapped with `<g>` tag to allow custom attributes storage.

```
 barGroupTag.selectAll("rect")
            .each( function () {
                       
                       var rectNode = this;
             
                       d3.select(rectNode.parentNode)
                         .insert("g")
                         .append( () => rectNode); 
                   }
                 );
```

The problem is that I need to access the original data associated  with each bar but unfortunately in the callback the second parameter returns the whole stack and not the single pair. So I can't figure out what is the element of such array which has been clicked. I checked for a third parameter passed to the callback but that's not the case. For example if I click on the [0,24] element (the bottom bar of the second stack), in the callback i get `event` as a `PointerEvent` object while `data` is an array of objects:

```
[[0,0],[0,24],[0,6],[0,7],[0,2],[0,7],[0,0]]
```

I can access the original data by using the `.data` field something like `data[index].data.label` or `data[index].data.count` but the problem is that **I don't know the value of index**.

This is strange because if I add an attribute to the rectangle with .attr the single object is received  (`d` value) and not the whole array so I can do something like:

```
.attr("xxx", d => {return d.data.count > 0 ? "aaa" : "bbb" } )
```

So why the value passed to the callback is the whole array of bars instead of the single element associated with the clicked bar ? How can I get the original data associated with the clicked bar ?

Comment: You're using d3 v6, right? When I go to [this example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/stacked-bar-chart) and add `.on("click", console.log)` to the bars, I see the individual values being logged. In the case of the bottom left bar, I see `[0, 5038433]`.

Comment: Yes  the version is `6.2.0` and `d3-collection` is at version `1.0.7`. I noticed the same behavior on another sample on Observable. The sample was working correctly but not mine. Regarding the sample that you linked I see some difference in the way the `d3.stack` function is used. Also the selections are slightly different where the output of `d3.stack` is used. I will try to make some changes.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the `<rect>` node are manually wrapped with a `<g>` tag (see the updated code). This was the problem. This operation was changing the data associated with the `rect`. After removing that code the onclick callback reported the correct pair value.

Comment: Nice, so it's solved now?

Comment: If that solved your problem I suggest you either write a self-answer or, preferrably, delete the post altogether as there is not much to take away from it for the rest of us.

Comment: @altocumulus I think there is still value in knowing what you shouldn't do in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by the statement `barGroupTag.selectAll("rect").each(...)` where I was manually wrapping each `rect` with `g` tag. For unknown reasons this operation was also changing the data associated with each rect. After removing that code the onclick callback reported the correct pair data object.

So be careful with `selectAll("xxx").each(...)` statement, especially if you are modifying the structure or hierarchy of the DOM objects and you defined event callbacks on such objects.